# Storage Class of Default Global variable (gcc compiler)?

Tags: c, variables, gcc, storage-class-specifier

In C, (GCC Compiler), what is the default storage class of global variables?

Let me share a code for example:

```
int i; 

void f()
{ --statements--}

main()
{ --- set of statements--- }
```

Am I correct if I say that variable `i` would be static and not extern ?

Comment: Why would this be specific to GCC? Doesn't the language say what it is?

Comment: As far as I am aware. there are some differences between different compilers. In formal arguments, like --> int func(int x) , x can be register (in gcc) or  auto (in turbo c) based upon compiler version.

Comment: What's an _auto_ in Turbo C ??

Comment: @Doherty Function parameters have absolutely nothing to do with storage duration and linkage of file scope variables... That being said, all standard compilers behave the same in either case.

Comment: @Lundin. I am sorry. I didn't get that. Could you please rephrase that for me?

Answer (score 6):

In this code, `i` has *static storage duration*, and *external linkage*.

*Storage duration* refers to the lifetime of the variable's storage. *Static storage duration* means that the variable exists for the entire lifetime of the program.

*Linkage* refers to the relationship between names and objects. *External linkage* means that all instances of a name with external linkage denote the same object. Your `int i;` will match a declaration `extern int i;` from another translation unit.

The keyword `static` is used in different contexts as a storage duration specifier and as a linkage specifier, so it is not clear to ask whether a variable is `static`. Instead, the variable's storage duration and linkage should be considered.

Comment: Could you please share an example which to show the external linkage by default ? I encountered a linking error when ran the same.

Comment: And by external linkage, did you mean that the variable can be accessed by another different file/program written ? Or it would be accessible by the functions within the same program ?

Comment: @Doherty other files in the same program.  If you have a linking error then post a new question with your *exact* code (and the command you used to compile and link). But check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) first to see if the problem is mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following cases for variables declared outside of any function:

```
static int variableWithfileScope;  // Not exported. Only visible in current file.

int globalVariableThatIsExported;  // Exported. 

// Forward declaration. No variable defined.
extern int globalVariableThatIsDefinedSomewhereElse;
```

This is defined by the standard and is applicable to all C compilers.